# Uncaught reference error, "..." is not defined

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to load 3 characters from 5 difference websites and a concatenate them into one string, even though I'm using a try & catch statement the strings say'uncaught reference error' and any codes with numbers cause a 'unexpected tokens error'. I'm using the P5.js framework at the moment but willing to try plain .js.

Thanks

My code:

```
var data;
function setup(){

    var url = [];

    url[0] = 'https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt1?verify=NRpxYLm9hCkAkhy0OSjEPA%3D%3D.json'
    url[1] = 'https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt2?verify=NRpxYLm9hCkAkhy0OSjEPA%3D%3D.json'
    url[2] = 'https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt3?verify=NRpxYLm9hCkAkhy0OSjEPA%3D%3D.json'
    url[3] = 'https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt4?verify=NRpxYLm9hCkAkhy0OSjEPA%3D%3D.json'
    url[4] = 'https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt5?verify=NRpxYLm9hCkAkhy0OSjEPA%3D%3D.json'

    try{
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            data += loadJSON(url[i], gotData, 'jsonp') + ' '
        }
    } catch (data){
        console.log('oh well');
    }

}

function draw(){
    createCanvas(400,400);
    background(225);
    text(data, 0, 200);
}

function gotData(data){
    text(data, 100, 200);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the actual error printout?

Comment: `gotData, 'jsonp'` ... they should be the other way around, shouldn't they? `loadJSON(path,[jsonpOptions],[datatype],[callback],[errorCallback])` `dataType` appears before `callback` in that function syntax

Comment: Have you tried initializing your variable using `var data = "";`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON):

> Loads a JSON file from a file or a URL, and returns an Object. Note that even if the JSON file contains an Array, an Object will be returned with index numbers as keys.
>
> This method is asynchronous, meaning it may not finish before the next line in your sketch is executed.

That last line explains what's going on: the `loadJSON()` function is asynchronous, which means it doesn't directly return anything. So lines like this don't make sense:

```
data += loadJSON(url[i], gotData, 'jsonp') + ' '
```

Please see the examples in the reference to understand how to use the `loadJSON()` function correctly, but basically you either need to use a callback function or you need to use the `preload()` function.